# error TS2339: Property 'endsWith' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I get this error on the code block below.

`error TS2339: Property 'endsWith' does not exist on type 'string'`

```
let myList = angular.element(elem).attr("href").split("/");
let last = _.last<string>(myList);
if (last.endsWith("something")) {
   return last;
}
```

I have also discovered this link that shows that there is a function `endsWith(...)`.

http://definitelytyped.org/docs/typescript-services--typescriptServices/classes/typescript.stringutilities.html

Do I miss some `.d.ts` file or what?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`endsWith` is an [ES6 function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) so you need to target `ES6` in your TypeScript compiler settings or you can add an interface for it:

```
interface String {    
    endsWith(searchString: string, endPosition?: number): boolean;
};
```

[[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20String%20%7B%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20endsWith(searchString%3A%20string%2C%20endPosition%3F%3A%20number)%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test%20%3D%20%22lala%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aif%20(test.endsWith(%22la%22))%20%7B%0D%0A%09console.log(%22OK!%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D)]

Comment: ES6 function definitions are located here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts for future reference.

Comment: In the end I replaced with something else using `indexOf`, since I had issues with the linter.

Answer (score 27):

While compiling your typescript code, please point the target to ES6.

```
tsc --target ES6 "filename"
```

Comment: Best straight forward way :D

Comment: @SharifYazdian - why is this the "best" way? It may be straightforward, but changing the target to ES6 means potential issues with browser version compat.

Comment: Or, if you need to do that repetitively, create `tsconfig.json` and add: 

`{
    "compilerOptions": {"target":"es6"}
}`

Comment: guess not good idea. we can't insist to go for "es6" for a solution when user require to go for "es5"

Answer (score 3):

**Here : I used VS code as an IDE**
**Issue was :**

```
let fName:String = "Yokey";
console.log(fName.anchor("url"));
```

**will result in :**

```
PS C:\MYahya\OS_DEV\typescript_lrn\1> tsc main.ts
main.ts(2,19): error TS2339: Property 'anchor' does not exist on type 'String'.
```

**Solution :**
I should include the following `tsconfig.json` file in the project:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "baseUrl": "../types",
        "typeRoots": [
            "../types"
        ],
        "types": [],
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    }
}
```

Then I used `tsc` (without file name) so the transpiler would use the `tsconfig.json` to transcompile all type script files hosted in the directories to `js` files.

Answer (score 0):

if youre using intelliJ IDE like WebStorm, click on the area where your project files are on the left then search for tsconfig.json. In that file you will see your es set to an older version just change the "target": "es3" to the latest like "target": "es2018"

Answer (score 0):

- Target ES6(Java Script version) in your TypeScript compiler settings using below command :

  ```
   Command:   tsc --target ES6 main.ts
  ```
- If you want to transpile and run the file at the same time then use
  below command :

  ```
   Command : tsc --target ES6 main.ts | node main.js
  ```