# using typescript and babel-polyfill results in compiler errors

Tags: typescript, babeljs

I am using babel-polyfill together with typescript.

When i use the function string.includes() I get an error

> Error TS2339: Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string'

There is a similar question in stack overflow: [error TS2339: Property 'endsWith' does not exist on type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431923/error-ts2339-property-endswith-does-not-exist-on-type-string)

The answer there is to extend the custom interface String

```
interface String {    
    endsWith(searchString: string, endPosition?: number): boolean;
};
```

I don't like this idea too much because this means that i will have to fix every es6 polyfill feature this way.

Is there a way to tell typescript that he should use the es6 definitions, but transpile to es5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a compiler option to turn this on, however you could reference the `lib.es6.d.ts` file directly:

```
///<reference path="../path/to/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts" />
```

or use a shim library like `es6-shim` to get the types, but not include the js file as babel will transpile it for you.

```
tsd install es6-shim
```