# .startsWith throws error while using typescript

Tags: typescript, discord.js

Whenever I use `.startsWith()`, it gives me this error:

```
Property 'startsWith' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

It works if I try `.startsWith()` on `index.js`, but not `index.ts`.

Here is what I have:

```js
client.on("message", function (msg) {
    if (msg.author.bot) {
        return;
    }
    if (!msg.content.startsWith(ConfigFile.config.prefix)) {
        return;
    }
    msg.channel.send(msg.author.username + " this better work.");
});
```

Comment: Can you show your tsconfig.json please?

Comment: Chances are your `tsconfig.json` does not have the `es6` lib included, or have set the `target` to `es5`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error TS2339: Property 'endsWith' does not exist on type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431923/error-ts2339-property-endswith-does-not-exist-on-type-string)

Comment: diouze, here it is
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES3",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "removeComments": true,
        "strict":true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        },
        "include": [
            "src", "index.js", "index.ts"
        ],
        "exclude": [
            "node_modules"
        ]
}

Comment: THANK YALL SO MUCH I CHANGED ES3 to es6. Thanks!!!